# Restore Database from bak file

Tags: c#, sql, .net

I'm trying to restore a database from a bak file. I found some code on how to do it grammatically but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I'm getting an error:

Error:
Restore failed for Server 'www.freegamedata.com'.

I assume because i'm remotely connected? I'm not sure. The bak file is not on the server machine. I'm trying to build a desktop application that will install my database on the users server using my file. Here is my code:

```
 private void Restore_Database()
    {
        try
        {
            Server server = new Server(Properties.Settings.Default.SQL_Server);
            string filename = "Test.bak";
            string filepath = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\file\\" + filename;
            Restore res = new Restore();

            res.Database = Properties.Settings.Default.SQL_Database;      
            res.Action = RestoreActionType.Database;
            res.Devices.AddDevice(filepath, DeviceType.File);
            res.PercentCompleteNotification = 10;
            res.ReplaceDatabase = true;
            res.PercentComplete += new PercentCompleteEventHandler(res_PercentComplete);  
            res.SqlRestore(server);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

I'm not sure if I'm going about this the correct way. I'd like to add my database with my data to the users server as a base database. Am I doing something wrong? My connection string is good so I know its not a connection issue.

Comment: Which variable in the code is having `www.freegamedata.com` as part of its value?

Comment: Probably not due to the connection. That should be irrelevant assuming the connection is working remotely outside of the application. However, the file being on a different computer could be the problem. Is there an inner detail to the error? Are you sure the file path to the remote location is a valid UNC and the SQL Agent Service log on as user has file and share access?

Comment: www.freegamedata.com is the server

Comment: Yes the connection is working in the application and outside the application. I agree I think that is the issue is the fact its a different machine. I have an idea I think for a work around and please feel free to tell me there is a better option. I was talking to my co worker and we thought it might be worth our time to create a script to first build the data base with the tables & procs. Then import the data from an excel spread sheet or something else.

Comment: I'm not sure what the best route would be at this point but it will need to be done remotely. I need to take into account the users setting this up may or may not have their sql setup locally. I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a workaround for those whom do not have local access. This is a bit involved so I hope I explain this correctly and it makes sense.

Also note you will need to export your data to an excel spreadsheet before you do the steps listed below.

Exporting Data
Part 1:
Backup Your DATA!

This is a pretty simple process. Open SQL Management Studio and right click on your database. Choose export data and export it as an excel spreadsheet 2007. I'm not going to give detailed steps on this part because its pretty basic and you can google it. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Part 2:
Delete your database for testing purposes but make sure you have a working backup before you delete your database.

Importing Data
Part 1:
You need to create a script that will build your database for you automatically. You can do this by logging into SQL management Studio and right click on the database and choose:

- Task -> Generate scripts

you should only need the default information. However, if your like me, I excluded the users in the list. This will generate a large SQL script.

Part 2:
Next you will want to store this file in your solution/project. Make sure you right click it and choose always copy or or copy if newer. I think that's the options.  Basically it just copies your file when you debug or build it. This is critical because you will need to access this file to execute the script. Next you need to make a SQL function similar to mine to execute the script:

```
public bool SQLScript_ExecuteSQLScript(string ScriptLocation)
        {
            try
            {
                //5 min timeout
                SqlConnection SQLConn = new SqlConnection(cn + "; Connection Timeout = 300;");
                string script = File.ReadAllText(ScriptLocation);
                Server server = new Server(new ServerConnection(SQLConn));

                server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery(script);

                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

In my code sample please note I changed my timeout to 5 minutes. In the event you have a large script you may need to adjust the timeout to make sure your script fully executes.

Congrats you have rebuilt your database.

Part 3:
Load SQL Management Studio and make sure your database has been rebuilt successfully. You should see all your tables and Stored Procs but no data. If this is true, great you can continue. If not please go back and review your script. If you have SQL comments in your script, you may need to remove them. I had to in order for my script to execute without errors.

Part 4:
Now you need to import your data from your excel spreadsheet you created earlier. If your like me, you had multipal sheets. If you have multipal sheets then you will want to make a list to loop through each item in your list to import the sheets. If not then you can ignore my code on the list. I also put mine in a background worker but you don't need to depending on the size of your data. Also note I created a separate class containing my list but you dont have to do that if you don't want too. My sheet names are Table_1, Table_2 and Table_3 your will be differently most likely.

Sample Sheet List:

```
public List<string> GetTestTableList()
        {
            try
            {
                List<string> testlist = new List<string>();
                testlist.Add("Table_1");
                testlist.Add("Table_2");
                testlist.Add("Table_3");

                return testlist;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
```

Part 5:
Next we will import the data from excel into SQL. This is a function I made but you can modify this to meet your needs.

Function:

```
private bool Import_Data_Into_SQL(string filepath, string SheetName, string Database, string Schema)
        {
            try
            {
                // sql table should match your sheet name in excel
                string sqltable = SheetName;

                // select all data from sheet by name  
                string exceldataquery = "select * from [" + SheetName + "$]";

                //create our connection strings - Excel 2007 - This may differ based on Excel spreadsheet used
                string excelconnectionstring = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source='" + filepath + " '; Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;";
                string sqlconnectionstring = Properties.Settings.Default.SQL_Connection;

                //series of commands to bulk copy data from the excel file into our sql table 
                OleDbConnection oledbconn = new OleDbConnection(excelconnectionstring);
                OleDbCommand oledbcmd = new OleDbCommand(exceldataquery, oledbconn);
                oledbconn.Open();
                OleDbDataReader dr = oledbcmd.ExecuteReader();
                SqlBulkCopy bulkcopy = new SqlBulkCopy(sqlconnectionstring);
                bulkcopy.DestinationTableName = Database + "." + Schema +"." + sqltable;

                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    bulkcopy.WriteToServer(dr);
                }

                dr.Close();
                oledbconn.Close();

                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

I hope this helps. This was my workaround solution. Originally I wanted/tried to import my data using the .bak file but as pointed out above you can only do that if the sql server is local. So I hope this work around helps those who where faced with a similar issue as me. I'm not marking this as the answer because the above post answers the question but I'm posting this in case someone else needs this workaround. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Restore file must be on server. For installation use SQL script. This can be generated by SQL Server Management Studio (including data).

Right click on database. Choose "Tasks" - "Generate scripts". On second page of wizard choose "Advanced" and find "Types of data to script". Select "Schema and data" and save script to file.

Then use this code to run script on database

```
string scriptText = File.ReadAllText(scriptFile, Encoding.Default);
ExecuteBatch executeBatch = new ExecuteBatch();
StringCollection commandTexts = executeBatch.GetStatements(scriptText);

using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(conn))
{
    sqlConnection.InfoMessage += SqlConnection_InfoMessage;
    sqlConnection.Open();

    for (int i = 0; i < commandTexts.Count; i++)
    {
        try
        {
            log.InfoFormat("Executing statement {0}", i + 1);
            string commandText = commandTexts[i];

            using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = sqlConnection.CreateCommand())
            {
                log.Debug(commandText);
                sqlCommand.CommandText = commandText;
                sqlCommand.CommandTimeout = 300;
                int r = sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                log.DebugFormat("{0} rows affected", r);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.Warn("Executing command failed", ex);

            try
            {
                sqlConnection.Open();
            }
            catch (Exception ex2)
            {
                log.Error("Cannot reopen connection", ex2);
            }
        }
    }

    sqlConnection.Close();
}
```

Comment: I came up with a workaround for this and i'll post it pending if it works or not.